# Why aren't glass spoons used for eating?

Tags: utensils

Why aren't glass spoons used for eating? It seems it would solve the problem of metallic taste with some foods.

Comment: Perhaps because there is a risk of damaging the glass when taking a bite, which might result in cutting lips and swallowing bits of glass. When drinking from a glass, we don't touch it with our teeth as much. In fact, in this day and age, plastic spoons would be the most efficient.

Comment: Mmmm, nothing like the delicious food and glass combo of accidentally biting down too hard on your glass flatware.... also, having to replace your flatware every time you drop it.

Answer (score 6):

There has actually been some significant research into cutlery being made of the correct substance to match the food

Testing shows perceptible difference in tastes from various metals when combined with certain foods. Just as silver spoons and egg are an unpleasant experience, some metals (e.g. copper, zinc) acted as a catalyst and improved the taste experience of certain foods

We use wood and ceramic for similar reasons, often for the mouth feel of the cutlery and heat dispersion, e.g. hot soups with metal spoons can be painful

Glass would have it's place, but probably not to dissimilar to porcelain (ceramic). Glass spoons are available, but rare

[image: glass spoon]

Some references:

[Institute of Making - Sensoaesthetic Properties of Materials](http://www.instituteofmaking.org.uk/research/sensoaesthetic-properties-of-materials/)

[Fine Dining Lovers - Cutlery food science](http://www.finedininglovers.com/blog/news-trends/cutlery-food-science/)

Answer (score 1):

There was never a need, as there was no benefit.

Spoons made from wood, nacre, horn or porcelain were widely available and don't come with the disadvantages of glass, like insufficient resistance to sudden temperature changes or shock resistance.

Borosilicate glass was invented in the late 19th century, so it wasn't available at a time where it might have had a greater influence on culture.

Porcelain spoons are cheap, with no apparent disadvantages, are widely accepted and do match with other kitchenware.